How does the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm sample from the target distribution when it only uses a proportional distribution?
I've recently started researching the M-H algorithm, and to my understanding, it's used to generates samples from a complex target distribution P(x) by using a proportional distribution f(x). The idea being that the samples use an acceptance probability based on P(x_new)/P(x_old) which is equivalent to f(x_new)/f(x_old). My question is how the samples converge directly to P(x) and not to some other distribution proportional to P(x). For example, if the target distribution was P(x)/2 instead, wouldn't the M-H algorithm behave the exact same way?

P(x)/2 isn’t a valid probability distribution if P(x) indeed is one. This is because you can pull constants out of integrals. And if the integral of P(x) sums to 1, then half that is…0.5, which is not a valid distribution. Nonetheless, these two are proportional to each other.

So in the case where P(x) is a probability distribution, any proportional distribution f(x) cannot be a probability distribution?

If you took a valid density function (which among other conditions, integrates to 1) and multiplied the density by a constant other than 1, ($c$, say), what would this rescaled function integrate to?


samples from a complex target distribution $p(x)$ by using a proportional distribution $f(x)$

We are talking of the same distribution when
$$p(x)\propto f(x)$$
as both functions induce the same density
$$\dfrac{p(x)}{\int_\mathsf X p(y)\,\text dy}
=\dfrac{f(x)}{\int_\mathsf X f(y)\,\text dy}$$
and the relative masses of two arbitrary measurable sets $\mathsf A$ and $\mathsf B$ are the same for both
$$\dfrac{\int_\mathsf A p(y)\,\text dy}{\int_\mathsf B p(y)\,\text dy}
=\dfrac{\int_\mathsf A f(y)\,\text dy}{\int_\mathsf B f(y)\,\text dy}$$
This is why a Metropolis-Hastings step is identical when using $p(\cdot)$ and $f(\cdot)$, with acceptance probability
$$\dfrac{p(x^\text{new})}{p(x^\text{old})}\,\dfrac{\mathfrak m(x^\text{new},x^\text{old})}{\mathfrak m(x^\text{old},x^\text{new})}=
\dfrac{f(x^\text{new})}{f(x^\text{old})}\,\dfrac{\mathfrak m(x^\text{new},x^\text{old})}{\mathfrak m(x^\text{old},x^\text{new})}$$
hence converging to the same stationary distribution with density $p(\cdot)$,and also why the acceptance rejection algorithm does not require the normalisation constant to be known, accepting simulation from $q(x)\propto g(x)$ with probability
$$\dfrac{p(x)/q(x)}{\max_y p(y)/q(y)}=\dfrac{f(x)/g(x)}{\max_y f(y)/g(y)}$$

I have nothing to add here other than that I'm a fan of your work and hope that others reading this answer know that you are a legend in the MCMC space.
